# How to make tabulator ajax call in wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wp-localize-script

As per [tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) documentation the ajax request can be made using the format like this

Ajax documentiation : http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/data#ajax

```
  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  ajaxURL:aglAjax.ajax_url,
  ajaxParams:{tabledata:aglAjax.data},
  ajaxConfig:{
        method: 'GET',
        mode:"cors", //set request mode to cors
        credentials: "same-origin", //send cookies with the request from the matching origin
         headers: {
             "Accept": "application/json", //tell the server we need JSON back
             "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", //fix to help some frameworks respond correctly to request
             "Content-type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //set the character encoding of the request            
        },
  },
ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        //url - the URL of the request
        //params - the parameters passed with the request
        //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.
        alert("Response Recived");
        console.log(response);
        return response; //pass the data array into Tabulator
    },
});
```

I am passing the data using localize script and tested if the data is passed. I am able to pass the variables, they show up correctly but I get 400 error every time ..not sure where I am making the mistake..can't tabulator ajax method be used in WordPress?

Comment: Where are you sending the request? What is `aglAjax.ajax_url`? Your site? Or someone elses?

Comment: @JacobPeattie it's my site only

Comment: Ok, so it's not going to magically return data by itself. Have you got code for handling the request and returning a response? Why isn't it in the question?

Comment: hmm `ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response)` does n't it return? it's in the request and data is in the localize script

Comment: What? The point of AJAX is to get data from the server. If you already have the data why are you sending it back to the server via AJAX?

Comment: @JacobPeattie ah oh ..that's correct .what am I doing .. I am really dumb. thank you